# What is the difference between a function object and a callable object?

Tags: javascript, function, callable

I recently saw the [presentation about the changes in ECMAScript 5](http://google-caja.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/html/es5-talk/es5-talk.html). And there was a [slide](http://google-caja.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/html/es5-talk/img31.html) with this statement:

> *Function* vs *Callable*
>
> ```
> typeof f === 'function'                       // → f is Callable
> ({}).toString.call(f) === '[object Function]' // → f is a Function
> ```

Can anyone explain to me what the difference between *Function* and *Callable* is?

Comment: Links are now dead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking, an object can be callable without being a function.  In a language where everything is an object (including functions), callable objects don't have to descend from a Function class.

In JS, it looks like a Callable is anything that has the internal [[Call]] method (identified by a typeof of 'function', as opposed to 'object').  A Function (as used in the slide) is a descendant of the Function object.  I could be wrong, but within a script you can only create Functions while the ECMAScript implementation can define Callables that aren't Functions.

If you try the code fragment from the slide with both anonymous functions/function expressions and with declared functions, the results are the same.

```
typeof function() {}; // == 'function'
({}).toString.call(function() {}) // == '[object Function]'
function foo() {}
typeof foo; // == 'function'
({}).toString.call(foo) // == '[object Function]'
```

Comment: And to enlighten outis' response, here is a discussion on how it came to be: http://bugs.ecmascript.org/ticket/153

Comment: Further information:

(function(){}).constructor; // → Function prototype
({}).constructor;  // → Object prototype

Comment: @FranCorpier That link is bad. Can you update it? It looks like it could be an interesting discussion.

Comment: @Icode4food: the ticket doesn't appear to exist on the site anymore, but the Wayback Machine archived it: http://web.archive.org/web/20091228035416/http://bugs.ecmascript.org/ticket/153

Comment: That link is dead now too

Comment: @TimSeguine the link is up now.