# Javascript toString quirk

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a simple function defined that does nothing:  `function fn() { }`

Now, when I run `toString(fn)` I get "[object Object]".  When I run `toString.call(fn)` I get "[object Function]".  Does anyone know why I get a more specific type when using the `call` method?

EDIT: This behavior is exhibited in FireFox run through FireBug console. Both `toString.constructor` and `toString.call.constructor` yield "Function()".

Comment: Details please. Are you calling this in a JavaScript interpreter? Which one? Rhino? jrunscript? which version?

Comment: Interestingly, as far as I know, toString is a method defined on the Object prototype, and not a built-in function. So, the question is, whose toString are you calling, and what argument is it receiving?

Comment: I ran this code through the Firebug 1.4.5 Console. The reason I got curious is because I saw toString.call used like this in the jQuery source code and started experimenting. I ran the code EXACTLY as it is shown in the question (so no "someobject.toString").

Comment: This can be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897103

Answer (score 11, accepted):

toString doesn't accept arguments, so `toString(fn)` is the same as just `toString()`, which returns an implicit global object, converted to string. `toString.call(fn)` calls `global.toString` passing function object as this, but since `global.toString` is a method of Object, the result is different from `Function.toString`.

Comment: Thanks also for pointing out the obvious flaw in my experiment: I forgot that I wasn't passing fn as a parameter into call but as the context! Now it all makes total sense.